# TimeZone and GetOffset for getting sunrise and sunset

Tags: android, xamarin, timezone-offset

I saw this link: https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/blob/master/OsmAnd-java/src/net/osmand/util/SunriseSunset.java

I put TimeZone this way: Java.Util.TimeZone.Default.

The function is: public SunriseSunset(double dfLatIn, double dfLonIn, Date dateInputIn, Java.Util.TimeZone tzIn)

We have "dfTimeZoneIn = 1.0 * tzIn.GetOffset(dateInputIn.Time) / 3600000;"

dateInputIn is new Date()

My problem: outputs (isDaytime(), ... ) are not right. The problem is with my work?

Comment: How are you calling this java code from Xamarin?  Did you port it to C#?  Or  did you create an Android binding library for it?

Comment: Yes, I port it to C#.

Comment: If you ported ~500 lines of java to c# then, yes, it's reasonable to think that you might have made a mistake that is causing your problem.  You'll need to take the time to debug your code to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Then my problem is not in the time zone? "dfTimeZoneIn" is correct? and This code will give me the correct answer?

Comment: I don't know.  All you have told us is that the "outputs are not right".  It is not clear what, if any, steps you have actually taken to attempt to debug this on your own.